# Difference between HttpClients.createSystem() vs HttpClients.createDefault()?

Tags: java, http, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm looking at the methods for creating a ClosableHttpClient in [`org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients.html) and I see the two possible methods:

- `.createDefault()`: *Creates CloseableHttpClient instance with default configuration*
- `.createSystem()`: *Creates CloseableHttpClient instance with default configuration based on system properties.*

What is the difference between the two? I'm aware that [it is possible to set up a custom client with `.custom()` to override certain behaviors](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management) however my remaining questions are:

- What are the defaults associated with `.createDefault()`?
- What system properties affect `.createSystem()`?
- Is it possible to modify the behavior of future clients that are created with `.createDefault()` or `.createDefault()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historic reasons (going back to early 200x) HttpClient does not take system properties into account by default.

> What are the defaults associated with .createDefault()?

Those are project defaults chosen by HttpClient developers

> What system properties affect .createSystem()?

- ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm
- javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType
- javax.net.ssl.trustStore
- javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider
- javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
- ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm
- javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType
- javax.net.ssl.keyStore
- javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider
- javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
- https.protocols
- https.cipherSuites
- http.proxyHost
- http.proxyPort
- https.proxyHost
- https.proxyPort
- http.nonProxyHosts
- https.proxyUser
- http.proxyUser
- https.proxyPassword
- http.proxyPassword
- http.keepAlive
- http.maxConnections
- http.agent

> Is it possible to modify the behavior of future clients that are created with .createDefault() or .createDefault()?

Of course, by way of `HttpContext`